# How to redirect to page 404 not found

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

What is the easiest way to configure routes, so that when a non-existent route is accessed, it is redirected to page 404 not found?

*Vue-Router*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

keyword **navigation guards** : https://forum.vuejs.org/t/best-practice-to-redirect-to-404-a-dynamic-route/35445/2

keyword **vue router custom 404** ( tutorial) : https://reactgo.com/vue-router-404-page/

as @Simon correctly stated you will need `{ path: '*', component: NotFound }` as last array element of `routes[]`  in your  `const router = new VueRouter({`

Answer (score 1):

If you add a route at the end to catch all:

```
 { path: "*", component: NotFoundPage }
```

Should do it, but make sure it is the last route

Answer (score 1):

in your `route.js`

```
path:"*":
redirect:"/404"
```

That will redirect missing routes in vue-router to /404. Make sure your /404 is loaded with component